# apt-get update throws error for key in 1 instance but not in second one, both identical

Tags: linux, ubuntu, public-key, influxdb

I'm trying to install influxdb in one of my instances, and I went and read many articles, and none of them worked, I went for the official [documentation](https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/) and followed instructions, and they still didn't work. I also read many post where they say the changed the key and how to update it and all, but they all basically say to run the commands on official documentation.

I followed instructions on official site, and ran:

```
wget -q https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive_compat.key
gpg --with-fingerprint --show-keys ./influxdata-archive_compat.key
echo '393e8779c89ac8d958f81f942f9ad7fb82a25e133faddaf92e15b16e6ac9ce4c influxdata-archive_compat.key' | sha256sum -c && cat influxdata-archive_compat.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg > /dev/null
echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg
sudo apt-get update
```

And I keep getting:

```
Err:6 https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: GPG error: https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
E: The repository 'https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So, not finding any additional information about this, every site said exactly the same. I also tried:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E
```

With no luck.

I decided to install it in another instance, with exactly the same configuration. The first group of commands ran with no problems.

I was able to install it running:

```
wget -q https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive_compat.key
gpg --with-fingerprint --show-keys ./influxdata-archive_compat.key
echo '393e8779c89ac8d958f81f942f9ad7fb82a25e133faddaf92e15b16e6ac9ce4c influxdata-archive_compat.key' | sha256sum -c && cat influxdata-archive_compat.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg > /dev/null
echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install influxdb2
```

I don't know if there could be some sort of cache or something.

This is the key list for the working instance:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-244:~$ apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg
----------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2023-01-18 [SC] [expires: 2026-01-17]
      9D53 9D90 D332 8DC7 D6C8  D3B9 D8FF 8E1F 7DF8 B07E
uid           [ unknown] InfluxData Package Signing Key <support@influxdata.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

And here it is for the one not finding public key:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-11:~$ apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid           [ unknown] Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg
----------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2023-01-18 [SC] [expires: 2026-01-17]
      9D53 9D90 D332 8DC7 D6C8  D3B9 D8FF 8E1F 7DF8 B07E
uid           [ unknown] InfluxData Package Signing Key <support@influxdata.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mosquitto-dev-ubuntu-mosquitto-ppa.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa1024 2009-12-03 [SC]
      77B7 346A 5902 7B33 C10C  AFE3 5E64 E954 262C 4500
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad mosquitto

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

What could possibly be wrong?